# Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, angularjs, zend-framework

now i work with angular js & zend framework and i have this problem trying to send data with post but there is a problem with zend not consedering $request as an object here is my script

```
app.controller('MyLogin', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.form = {username : '', password : ''};
$scope.submit = function () {
$http({
    url: '/login',
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data: {
        'username' : $scope.form.username,
        'password' : $scope.form.password
    },
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);

});
}
```

});

and the in the controller

```
  class LoginController extends AbstractRestfulController  {
    public function indexAction() {
     $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $request = json_decode($data);
        var_dump($request);
        var_dump($request->username); }}
```

for var_dump($request) i got

```
 object(stdClass)#194 (2) {
   ["username"]=>
   string(7) "yassine"
   ["password"]=>
   string(7) "yassine"
    }
```

and for var_dump($request->username);

```
   string(7) "yassine"
```

but still this error

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\zendf\module\Login\src\Login\Controller\LoginController.php on line 21

Comment: which one is `'line 21` of LoginController.php ?

Comment: seems like you are getting that notice after the line with `$request->username`.  So, as @YvesLeBorg said, what is on line 21..?

Comment: var_dump($request->username);

Comment: well, your php seems to be interpreting a different file than the one shown ...  or that is not line 21. Because right now, you are succeeding in getting a property of a non-`non-object`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs for [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it says in Example #3 that the key and value must be enclosed in double quotes. Try swapping your single quotes for double when building your JSON, otherwise it isn't considered valid.